# Why we use NULL in sqlite3_prepare_v2( )

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, sqlite

Please can anyone tell me why we write `NULL` in the fifth parameter below?

```
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as your `sql` has only one statement, you don't need to use the fifth parameter. When `sql` has more than one statement, you can receive a pointer to the beginning of the next statement.
For example:

```
const char* sql =
  "DROP TABLE price_list;"
  "CREATE TABLE price_list ( item TEXT, price INTEGER)";
while ( *sql ) {
  sqlite3_stmt* statement;
  sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &statement, &sql);
  sqlite_step(statement);
  sqlite_finalize(statement);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you don't care about the uncompiled part of the SQL statement. From [the docs](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html):

> If pzTail is not NULL then *pzTail is made to point to the first byte past the end of the first SQL statement in zSql. These routines only compile the first statement in zSql, so *pzTail is left pointing to what remains uncompiled.

It's useful to have this if you have a string with many SQL statements, but if you don't then it's just cruft.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams